# alternative for passing references around in python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I'm relatively new to python and oop, and i have a question around the design of my code for a hobby project.

I created a lot of variables in my main program. These variables are lists of objects (not configuration parameters and not constants). The objects in the lists are sprites.

I'm passing these variables around between objects, by calling methods and passing the variables around as arguments for a specific method. (pass-by-reference)

For example:

```
spritelist = [Sprite(...), Sprite(..)]

mycollisiondetector = CollisionDetector()

mycollisiondetector.check_collision(spritelist)
```

Then, in class CollisionDetector, spritelist is passed to "private" methods of the class. These private methods call other methods, and keep passing spritelist ... .

So, my question is just this: is there an alternative for endlessly passing variables around from one method to another ?

Comment: Can you please post some of the codes so that we can help you.

Comment: Your question is very non-specific and therefor impossible to answer. What does "remove the variables from my file" even mean? How can a program work without variables? I'd say: you think to much.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it would be too pythonic, but you can always keep a lot of variables in a file and just "import" or "execfile" it. I use it for, for example, passing the main program different initial inputs or keep a lot of scientific constants that I use often.

Comment: Are the variables you want to remove global configuration variables?

Comment: @hop: i appreciate your answer and concerns. I was thinking on placing variables in a separate file, and then include/import the file into my main program. I know it exists in at least one other programming language, but i'm not sure it exists in python.

Comment: @goncalopp: Nope. Mostly references to lists of objects. The objects are sprites.

Comment: In that case you can either directly import the file (which means the file has always the same name) or you want to pass a file name as an input when calling the program (see sys.argv) and then execute it with execfile within the code. I've used both tricks, as I said before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with instance variables (not configuration constants), it's considered bad practice to separate the variables into a module (a different file), since you're mixing instance state and global state.

If you have many references being passed around repeatedly, this is usually a indicator of bad class hierarchy design. You may want to consider subclassing, or defining a new class for your variables and passing a reference to it. The details will depend on your specific situation - it's hard to tell without seeing the code.